# Best way to group data in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, group-by, grouping

I have a list of players which belong to a group each. How can I use a filter to list the users per group?

[{name: 'Gene', team: 'team alpha', country: 'US'},
 {name: 'George', team: 'team beta' country: 'CA'},
 {name: 'Steve', team: 'team gamma' country: 'JP'}, {name: 'Paula', team: 'team beta' country: 'US'},
 {name: 'Scruath of the 5th sector', team: 'team gamma' country: 'JP'}];

If group by team,it should be:

**team alpha**

- Gene

**team beta**

- George
- Paula

**team gamma**

- Steve
- Scruath of the 5th sector

and when i change the group attribute to 'country':

**US**

- Gene
- Paula

**CA**

- George

**JP**

- Steve
- Scruath of the 5th sector

and i also want to add new person data dynamic like use 
 `<button ng-click="addNew()">New</button>`

Comment: @Franquis I found this post http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-Grouping-Nested-ngRepeat-Lists-In-AngularJS.htm but it doesn't solve my last problem, when i want to add a new data it will run this whole function again, group the whole data within the new data again..